# D3.js stacked bar chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, bar-chart

I've spent enough time modifying the [stacked bar chart sample](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1134768) that it would be wise to get a second pair of eyes to look at what I'm doing wrong. The modified sample is in a [js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H32yz/4/).

My main changes are these:

1: On line 10 reversed the array for range
    `y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0])`

2: On lines 17 and 22 added axis

```
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                .scale(x)
                .orient("bottom")
                .tickFormat(format);
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                .scale(y)
                .orient("left")
```

3: Line 62 changed the addition of y0 and y (this is the change that might be creating problem)

```
.attr("y", function (d) { return y(d.y) - y(d.y0); })
```

As you can see bars are going way above the specified height.

If someone could tell me what I'm doing wrong I'd be very thankful. I spent too much time looking just by myself. I do think I'm very close as chart is displaying other than the height problem.

Comment: I know this isn't very helpful for your current problem (I'm not an expert with d3), but if you are just looking for a simple chart, I find that d3 is far too complicated to achieve what you are looking for. It is great for complicated stuff, but for easier things (like stacked charts) I usually use highcharts http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-stacked

Comment: @Pompey Thanks for the suggestion however currently I have much time invested in d3.js so will go with that for now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is one more change, which you haven't mentioned: that you the chart containing `g` is now translated to the top-left point instead of the bottom-left point, as was in the original plot.

Changing the following two lines around the line you mentioned will solve the problem:

```js
            .attr("y", function (d) { return y(d.y + d.y0); })
            .attr("height", function (d) { return y(d.y0) - y(d.y +d.y0); })
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/H32yz/14/)

This is how I generally do these calculations with an inverted scale such as `y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0])`:

[image: calculations with inverted scale]

Here, the point `S(y + y0)` will be the value of the point closer to the `top`, or with the lower `y` value, and the `height` of the bar will be = `S(y0) - S(y + y0)` or = `abs(S(y0+y) - S(y0))`, whichever you find more palatable.

However, to be honest, there is plenty of trial and error involved before I actually draw this down. Then I do more trial and error to find the solution and convince myself that this drawing helped.

So ... your mileage might vary. :)

Comment: Thanks so much for taking time to look through my code and finding the problem also for extra effort in creating the drawing to make it palatable. In fact I did understood the theory in drawing couple of hours ago but was still making a small mistake in setting height attribute but you got it right. Yes I missed to mention the change where g is transformed to top left. Thanks again so much.